# Where are the limits of cython's templates?

Tags: templates, typedef, cython

I've got this class but cannot figure out how to extern define with cython. The inner typedef is bugging me :

```
public:

 typedef ReturnType (*Method)(Parameter);
```

Here is the full class :

```
#ifndef LABCALLBACK2_H_
#define LABCALLBACK2_H_


namespace elps {


template < typename ReturnType, typename Parameter >
class LabCallBack2
{
public:

 typedef ReturnType (*Method)(Parameter);

 LabCallBack2(Method _method)
 {
    method         = _method;
 };

 ReturnType operator()(Parameter parameter)
 {
    return (*method)(parameter);
 };

 ReturnType execute(Parameter parameter)
 {
    return operator()(parameter);
 };

private:

 Method  method;

};


}  // namespace elps

#endif /* LABCALLBACK2_H_ */
```

I started with this, but what next ? Does cython provides a way to do this ?

```
cdef extern from "../inc/LabCallBack2.h" namespace "elps" :
    cdef cppclass LabCallBack2[ReturnType, Parameter]:
        LabCallBack2(?????????  _method)
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the next:

```
LabCallBack2(**void ***_method)
```

I had used this trick in other cases and it works fine with cython